# operating systems/ paging

Tags: operating-system

considering a demand paged system with page size of 2048 bytes and a total physical memory of 128K, can someone tell me how to calculate the length of the physical address.??

Answer (score 0):

Since the total physical memory is 128K and the page size is 2048 bytes, we can have 128*1024/2048 = 64 pages in memory at the same time. Hence we need log2(64) = 6 bits to index them all. Therefor the length of the physical address needs to be 6 bits.
The fact that it's a demand paging system doesn't change the length of the physical address, it will just (probably) make the system use less memory.

Comment: That's 6 bits for the *page index*.  It takes more bits to address each byte within a page.